# Installed awesome wm using ubuntu. How come it lists debian when I click on the "start button" at the top left?

Tags: ubuntu, awesome-wm

Does this mean I've installed the debian build of awesome or is this just how the setup is arranged?

To install I simply used sudo apt-get install awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu is a [Debian-based distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) and sometimes installs packages from the Debian repositories, or repositories that are shared with Debian distributions.  Just make sure any packages you install from Debian repositories are from source and not binary packages.

> Ubuntu builds on the foundations of Debian's architecture and
>   infrastructure, but has a different community and release process.

http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/ubuntu-and-debian

Comment: still mildly confused. So they're both distributions with separate communities, but Ubuntu based themselves on Debian at some stage but takes its own direction?

Am I right in saying that there's no such thing as Linux OS, because Linux is just the kernel which combines with other parts to make up the OS. Getting confused because it says Linux is an OS on the first line of the wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux

Comment: And how does GNU come into all this? I mean, it'd be nice if there was a diagram describing the relationships :P